# PHP form takes back to top

Tags: php

I have PHP included a PHP form in my portfolio, that you can see here http://www.tinybigstudio.com  The thing is that after SUBMIT, the page goes to TOP instead of staying at the bottom where the form is.

This is the PHP code I have:

```
<?php
//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
    }



    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
    if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    //Check to make sure comments were entered
    if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
        } else {
            $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
        }
    }

    //If there is no error, send the email
    if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = 'info@tinybigstudio.com'; //Put your own email address here
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email  \n\nComments:\n $comments";
        $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' .$subject = "You have mail, yes!" . "\r\n" . 'Te lo manda: ' . $name;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    }
}
?>
```

And this is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" size="50" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="required">

                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required">

                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                            <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" id="message" class="required"></textarea>

                        <input type="submit" value="S E N D" class="send" name="submit"  onmouseover="this.className='send_hover';"
                                     onmouseout="this.className='send';">
                    </form>



<?php if(isset($hasError)) { //If errors are found ?>
                <p class="error">Please check if you've filled all the fields with valid information. Thank you.</p>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { //If email is sent ?>
                <p><strong>Message Successfully Sent!</strong></p>
                <p>Thank you <strong><?php echo $name;?></strong> for sending a message!</p>
            <?php }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add an anchor to the contact form and use this as the form action.eg:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>#contact" >
```

and add this 'pseudo-link' right before the contact form

```
<a name="contact">Contact me</a>
```

Now after submit user will be send to the form directly and not the top of the page

Comment: It _is_ pretty. Though you need to work on your prose. "Texts", "bussy", "`" instead of "'" (e.g. "LET´S GET BUSSY") would prevent me from choosing you as a supplier.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are submitting it to the same page that you are on, therefore the browser goes effectively refreshes with the $_POST data. If you want to stop this you need to use AJAX to submit it so that it happens in the background. Take a look at the API - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/